# SQL query on conditional expressions

Tags: sql, join, group-by, pivot

I am starting an SQL crash course and I have this problem it's bugging me I can't find a solution and with lockdown I have no one I can ask. It's about conditional expressions. In the problem some people play different instruments and they play in duets occasionally in school. I need to find a query that retrieves a table with name and guitar (yes or no) if they play that instrument. I have to work with the following tables:
Table students

```
|  id | name        |  grade  | gender
+-----+-------------+---------+------
|  1  | John        |    12   |  M
|  2  | Andrew      |    11   |  F
|  3  | Abigail     |    11   |  F
|  4  | Simon       |    10   |  M
```

Table duets

```
| id | idStudent1 | idStudent2 | duetOf
+----+------------+------------+------
| 20 |    1       |    2       | Piano
| 35 |    2       |    4       | Piano
| 36 |    3       |    2       | Drums
| 37 |    4       |    1       | Drums
| 35 |    4       |    2       | Guitar
| 36 |    4       |    2       | Flute
| 37 |    4       |    3       | Piano
```

Query:

```
select s.name, Coalesce (d.duets, '(none)')
from students s, duet d
where s.id = d.idStudent1
  and s.id = d.idStudeant2
  and d.instrument = 'guitar'
```

Any tips on how I can tackle this kind of problem?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. It is great that you have the input tables, but an example of what you expect as output would make it possible to give a correct answer.

Comment: The duets are all of the same instrument?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    s.id,
    s.name,
    max(case when d.duetOf = 'Piano'  then 'Yes' else 'No' end) piano,
    max(case when d.duetOf = 'Guitar' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) guitar
from students s
left join duets d 
    on s.id in (d.idStudent1, d.idStudent2)
group by s.id, s.name
```

This generates one record for each record in `students`, with two columns that indicate whether the student belongs to a duet that plays guitar or piano.

If you need to display more columns from the `students` table, you can add them in both the `select` and `group by` clauses.

Comment: Thank you this is a very smart approach and it works smoothly. You make this seem like it's really easy. Been stressing out for a while. Thanks @GMB! appreciate the input. I will revise more these problems

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
select s.name, case when duetOf = 'Guitar' then 'Yes' Else 'No' End as Guitar  
from duet d
inner join students s on d.idStudent1 = s.Id or d.idStudent2 = s.Id
```